# Dimension and Base of $(E_{12} + E_{21} + E_{23} + E_{32})A = 0$ Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

You have a set:

$W = {A ∈ Mn(R) | (E_{12} + E_{21} + E_{23} + E_{32})A = 0}$.

You need to find out if this set is subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. I proofed it that way:

$(E_{12} + E_{21} + E_{23} + E_{32})A + (E_{12} + E_{21} + E_{23} + E_{32})B = (E_{12} + E_{21} + E_{23} + E_{32})(A+B)=0$ 
and
$λ(E_{12} + E_{21} + E_{23} + E_{32})A = (E_{12} + E_{21} + E_{23} + E_{32})λA=0$.

I think that I did correct this part of the task.

But I don't know how to do the second part. Instructions:

Let $n=3$.
Calculate dimension and define base.

I have an issue becouse I don't know how this matrix of $E$'s looks like. I would appriciate your help.

Comment: This matrix of E's looks like follows: $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with entry $1$ at position $(i,j)$, and zero entries otherwise.

Comment: So dimension is 2?

Comment: No, dimesnion is $n$. We consider $M_n(K)$.